# How to debug Pro*C code?

Tags: c, debugging

We have a legacy code written in Pro*C which now needs to refactored. is there any debugger which supports debugging pro c  code.

is it possible to debug using .c/.cpp produced after proc*C pre compilation

Comment: If you are looking for software your question is off-topic. But there is [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I have no specific experience with Pro*C, but inasmuch as the generated code is supposed to be usable with several C compilers to build an ordinary executable, you ought to be able to use your toolchain's standard debugger on it.  For instance, if GCC is among the supported compilers (and maybe even if not) then you should be able to debug the executable with `gdb`.

Comment: What do you get when you run your Pro*C code in a debugger?

Answer (score 4):

As can be read [here in chapter 9](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58233.pdf) the `LINES=YES` option adds `#line` C-preprocessor directives.  (Just search for the word 'debugging' in the above PDF, and you'll jump right to the correct page.)  Doing this allows you to debug the original Pro*C code.

Without the above option, you should still be able to debug, but the debugger will point to a completely wrong (too far) line as soon as you're passed the first Pro*C command (that has expanded to more lines).  The inserted `#line` directives simply correct this, without affecting the debug process in any other way; so if you can't debug already, you first need to sort that out.

Try to find the makefile (or build script) that calls `proc` and add the above option.

Be aware that the if you step through the code, the debugger may stay for several steps on each Pro*C command.  This is simply because Pro*C commands may expand to several lines of C code, which all got the same line number assigned.

I've had colleagues in my room use Pro*C a long time ago, and I vaguely remember that they were able to debug.  Also, as John Bollinger comments, it should all be possible because Pro*C is just a preprocessor which outputs regular C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

As I am working on Pro*C batches, now for around 1 year; we simply display the trace_message on the screen. It goes like:

define a variable:

## DEFINE a = 0

if(a == 0) printf("Opening the Cursor ");

(and at most of the code use)so, when program runs it will display what it is doing and what values it is fetching. we can also make a function to create a debug_log.txt instead of directly printing on screen whichever way you like.

and when you deploy the code in prod. just:

## DEFINE a = 1

I hope this may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to debug a Pro*C program. You must have gdb installed and setup. Follow the original link more more information.

```
gdb <program>

r - run program

b <line number> - set breakpoint

d <line number> - unset breakpoint

n -next line

s - step into

c - continue (to next breakpoint)

bt - backtrace

l <line number> - list the source code at <line number>

clear [line number] - clears the break point at [line]

q - quit

Watch <parameter> - Program stops when the value of the parameter changes
```

http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS2230/resources/gdb-intro.html

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html